# css hover effect size increasing affecting other elements

Tags: css, css-float

I have buttons and I added a hover effect to them to change their borders. It is affecting the layout of the menu.

```
element{
   border-width:0px;
}
element:hover{
   border:1px solid gray;
}
```

How can I do it without affecting the layout?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`box-sizing: border-box` will put the borders inside the box, should fix any sizing issues.

Answer (score 2):

The border width changes the dimension of the element, so you probably need to take the additional pixel into account. Perhaps something like this will do the trick.

```
element{
  border:1px solid transparent;
}
element:hover{
  border:1px solid gray;
}
```

Comment: logic i would like to do smart as Mash stated